# ffmpeg generating thumbnails with correct rotation?

Tags: php, ffmpeg

I'm running ffmpeg commands server-side in php. First im converting the uploaded file to .mp4 then generating a thumbnail from the file. The problem is that the thumbnails are rotated, because of the rotation tag in the video metadata. How can i add this rotation tag to the generated thumbnail, so that the thumbnails are also properly oriented?

```
        $getFromSecond = 5;
        $videoFile = $video_base . $_FILES['media']['name'];
        $pos = strpos($videoFile, '.');
        $videoFileName = substr($videoFile, 0, $pos);
        $videoFileName = $videoFileName . ".mp4";

        $cmd_convert = "$ffmpeg -i $videoFile -map_metadata 0 -vcodec copy -acodec copy -y $videoFileName && rm $videoFile";
        exec($cmd_convert);

        $imageFile = $thumb_base . $thumb_name[0] . '.jpg';
        $size='400x300';            

        $cmd_thumb = "$ffmpeg -i $videoFileName -an -ss $getFromSecond -s $size $imageFile";
        exec($cmd_thumb);
```

Comment: The issue really has nothing to do with PHP. Providing the complete console output from the `ffmpeg` command will show exactly what's going on.

Comment: @LordNeckbeard it is my understanding that php has the power to rotate images, as I'm not sure if it is possible to set a rotation tag when generating thumbnails with ffmpeg, the question was designed to encompass both php and ffmpeg, in hopes of finding the best solution.

Comment: There is most likely a solution with `ffmpeg`, but it is not possible to provide it without the console output.